# Cannot publish iOS push notification certificates changes of a linked iOS app in the Google Play Game Services

Tags: ios, google-play-services, google-play-games, leaderboard, achievements

I'm using Google Play Game Services for both the Android and iOS version of my game. While the Android version can be set up and used flawlessly, the same cannot be said with the iOS version. I've linked my game and I've entered the relevant data, except for the APNS certificate settings, which I forgot. And then I published the changes. Now, I'm trying to add the certificates, but everytime I tried to re-publish it again, it said "Some changes are not ready to be published yet. " without telling me what those changes are. And when I tried to see what has changed on the "Testing" page, it didn't say anything. There's an "in-out green arrow" in the Linked Apps, Testing, and Publishing sections. So right now I can't republish it with the new APNS certificates, and if I revert back, it will revert back to the linked app without the certificates. I'm confused because it won't let me publish the changes.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: consider changing to parse  :)

Comment: Hi User .. I'm referring to Parse.com.  It's much easier.  BTW, I might suggest, if you put a proper nick name on your account, you'll probably get more answers...